# Iterate over column to convert currency with the forex-python package

Tags: python, pandas, currency

I have a column ['currency'] and another one ['amount']. The column ['currency'] contains objects in this format: USD, EUR, SEK, AUD, etc.

I would like to convert all the ['amount'] values into USD by converting all the other currencies, and print the new conversion in a new column, but I got stuck at this point:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates

    c = CurrencyRates()

    y = ['currency']
    x = ['amount']

    for column in df['amount']:
       c.get_rate('USD', x)
```

Should I link every currency symbol with the respective amount?

Comment: Where is your data set?
Is it in Pandas?

Comment: @gtomer  yes, sorry. Pandas df from excel file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a df then this is the way to iterate over the rows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    c.get_rate(row['currency'], row['amount'])
```

I am not familiar with the get_rate function.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But the values in ['amount'] depends of the string in ['currency'], that is it needs to know what currency it is converting.

Comment: Then I guess it should be: c.get_rate(row['currency'], row['amount'])